# winget is not a cmdlet name

Tags: windows-10, winget

After a fresh install of Windows 10 with the latest updates i get the error that winget.exe is not a cmdlet.

The PATH variable is set to the correct directory. However the "winget.exe" is not in that directory with other WindowsApps. The Package Installer is installed and even shows up in the "uninstall apps" settings.

I think that it either put the winget.exe in a different directory or else i dont know.

On my other laptop winget works and is in the Path of the exact environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, it's likely the Microsoft Store hasn't yet updated the App Installer to the latest version right after the OS has installed on first login. If you update the Apps in the Microsoft Store, that should resolve this issue.

Alternatively, instructions are available at Microsoft Learn for downloading the MSIX packages and registering them for users on the system.

It's also possible to install and use the Microsoft.WinGet.Client PowerShell module which contains a "Repair-WinGetPackageManager" cmdlet.